# build opencv from source: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have built **OpenCV** from source. I follow this link [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html).

But when I try to **import cv2**, I get the following:

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I am new to opencv. Please help me with this.

Comment: I tried **sudo apt-get install python-opencv**. but not working!!

Answer (score 1):

Give us more details on what system you're using

Try adding this to your `~/.bashrc`
`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`